# pyspark apply function in parallel to data in many csv files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Can **pyspark** be used to efficiently read and process many .csv files?  As a minimal example, data are many .csv files each with 5 rows and 2 columns.  My real use case is many thousands of files each with few millions of rows and hundreds of columns (appx 10GB per file) on a filesystem or a cluster.

A quick and dirty **pandas** implementation is as follows (assuming `fns` is a list of .csv filenames, and processing is implemented as the max of column-means), but will be slow because files are read serially and processing uses a single core.

```
result = []
for fn in fns:
    df = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None)
    result.append(df.agg(func).max())
```

My expectation is that **pyspark** can both read and process files in parallel.

[image]

Comment: you can use `spark.read.csv` to read all the files in the folder (specify wild cards too if needed) which will be done in parallel (assuming all the files have the same schema, otherwise you'll have to think about how to merge the schemas). Also make sure you have enough executors and appropriate executor memory for the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your files have the same schema then you can directly read all the files using
`spark.read.csv`

And it seems your files don't have schema then you can provide your custom schema also

```
import pyspark.sql.types as t
schema = t.StructType([t.StructField('id',t.IntegerType(),True),
                       t.StructField('name',t.StringType(),True)])
df = spark.read.csv('path/to/folder',schema=schema)

#perform you aggregations on df now
```